# Converting VarChar to DateTime and skipping records with invalid dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got the following dataset:

```
CISS_STATUS       SVCDAT    BRANCD
                     .        68
                     .        68
R                    .        68
R                    .        68
                     .        68
                     .        68
                     .        22
R               01/01/2013    65
A               01/01/2014    22
A               01/01/2015    32
```

There's about 500K records and 60 other fields, but you get the point.  Anyway, what I want to do is write a WHERE clause that excludes records that don't have valid dates in them (i.e. the ones with dots in them), based on SVCDAT (which is a VarChar(10) data type).

When I try something like:

```
WHERE convert(datetime,SVCDAT,1) > '1/1/1900'
```

I get this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

When I try this:

```
WHERE CAST(SVCDAT as smalldatetime) > '1/1/1900'
```

I get this error:

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in 
an out-of-range value.
```

Anyone got any ideas on how to solve for this?

Comment: You can use ISDATE() to generate a derived table (or CTE) of only valid dates and then perform your query against that.

Comment: Was hoping to do it without generating another temp table, this is actually one step of a very lengthy process.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use `TRY_CONVERT`. It returns NULL if the value cannot be converted:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime, SVCDAT, 1) > '1/1/1900'
```

More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx).

Comment: Not sure why, the About states it's 2012, but it says TRY_CONVERT is not a built-in function

Comment: @JohnnyBones then you are not using SQL Server 2012. You are probably using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 but the database you are connecting to is not a SQL 2012.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: use `SELECT @@VERSION` to see  SQL Server's version and other information.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ISDATE()` function to filter the bad data. Then use the filter in where clause to filter the records greater then a given date

```
select * from 
(
select * 
from yourtable
where ISDATE(SVCDAT) = 1
) a
where convert(date,SVCDAT) > convert(date,'1/1/1900')
```

or use `TRY_CAST` function

```
select * from 
(
select * 
from yourtable
where try_cast(SVCDAT as date) is not null
) a
where convert(date,SVCDAT) > convert(date,'1/1/1900')
```

Comment: Not sure why, the About states it's 2012, but it says TRY_CAST is not a built-in function

Comment: Oddly enough, ISDATE worked in this case.  I just used **where ISDATE(SVCDAT) = 1** in my query and it worked fine.  Thanks!